# How to make modular helper in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, helper

i want to make a method inside a module (for grouping reason) that can be called as a `module.method`, something like this:

```
helpers do
  module UserSession
    def logged_in?
      not session[:email].nil?
    end
    def logout!
      session[:email] = nil
    end
  end
end
```

but when i try to call it using `UserSession.logged_in?` it said that logged_in is not UserSession's method

> undefined method `logged_in?' for UserSession:Module

when i move the method as UserSession's method:

```
helpers do
  module UserSession
    def self.logged_in?
      not session[:email].nil? # error
    end
    def self.logout!
      session[:email] = nil
    end
  end
end
```

it gives an error, that i could not access the `session` variable

> undefined local variable or method `session' for UserSession:Module

what is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: `include UserSession`?

Comment: so, are you implying that i should make module outside the sinatra's helpers method, then include it? it will have the same problem (cannot access session variable)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a different convention for the `helpers` method.

```
module UserSession
  def logged_in?
   not session[:email].nil?
  end
  def logout!
    session[:email] = nil
  end
end

helpers UserSession

get '/foo' do
  if logged_in?
    'Hello you!'
  else
    'Do I know you?'
  end
end
```

The module definition can of course be in another (`require`d) file.

Behind the scenes, `helpers <Module>` is doing an `include`, but not simply into the Sinatra application sub-class you are using for your app. The `include` needs to be made compatible with how `get`, `post` etc work their magic, and `helpers` does that for you.

Comment: no, i want to call the method with module name too.. `UserSession.logged_in?`

Comment: @Kokizzu: That may be possible, but I'm not sure how within Sinatra framework. The method needs access to the state of the request.

Comment: @Kokizzu "i want to call the method with module name too.. UserSession.logged_in?" - why?

Comment: to put the some function on their correct category... (UserSession, HtmlHelper, JsonHelper, etc)

Answer (score 2):

nevermind, i found the answer, i have tried `define_method('UserSession.logged_in?')` also, but no luck

last thing i've tried is:

```
# outside helpers
class UserSession
  @@session = nil
  def initialize session
    @@session ||= session
  end
  def self.check
    throw('must be initialized first') if @@session.nil?
  end
  def self.logged_in?
    self.check
    not @@session[:email].nil?
  end
  def self.logout
    self.check
    @@session.delete :email
  end
end
```

but something must be called first

```
before // do
  UserSession.new session
end
```

then it can be used as desired:

```
get '/' do
  if UserSession.logged_in?
    # do something here
  end
end
```

Comment: If this is intended to be hook into security or ownership code, you should probably also add an `after //` block which clears the stored session variable. Else it could well persist into the next request on the same process (in the simple case here that would be harmless, and over-written on next request, but it is a risky piece of data to have hanging around).

Comment: yes, this is a problem indeed.. when i do two request at once, it shows that the old static variable not yet erased.. >___<